# Automapper not working

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, many-to-many, automapper

I have 2 tables that saved family members and the below LINQ is 100% work and got result return. I tried to map using Automapper but it's does not work , the `customerViewItem`  does not have data and no error , could some one please advise, thanks in advance.

**POCO**

```
public  class Cust_ProfileTbl
{
    [Key]
    public long bintAccountNo { get; set; } 
    public string nvarCardName { get; set; }
    public string varEmail { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl> profileFamilyParents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl> profileFamilyChildren { get; set; }
}

public class Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl
{
    [Key]
    public int intProfileFamily { get; set; } 
    public long bintAccountNo { get; set; }
    public long bintAccountNoMember { get; set; }

    public virtual Cust_ProfileTbl custProfileParent { get; set; }
    public virtual Cust_ProfileTbl custProfileChild { get; set; }
}
```

**In onModelCreating**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl>()
       .HasRequired(m => m.custProfileParent)
       .WithMany(t => t.profileFamilyParents)
       .HasForeignKey(m => m.bintAccountNo)
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.custProfileChild)
            .WithMany(t => t.profileFamilyChildren)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.bintAccountNoMember)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

**ViewModels**

```
public class Profile  
{

    public long bintAccountNo { get; set; }
    public string varCardNo { get; set; }
    public string nvarCardName { get; set; }

    public string varEmail { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProfileFamily> profileFamilyParents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProfileFamily> profileFamilyChildren { get; set; }
    public Profile()
    {
        profileFamilyParents = new Collection<ProfileFamily>();
        profileFamilyChildren = new Collection<ProfileFamily>();
    }


}

public class ProfileFamily 
{
    public int intProfileFamily { get; set; }
    public long bintAccountNo { get; set; }
    public long bintAccountNoMember { get; set; }

   public Profile custProfileParent { get; set; }

}
```

**LINQ and AutoMapper**

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Cust_ProfileTbl, bool>> wherep = (x) => x.bintAccountNo.Equals(1);

Cust_ProfileTbl rs = (from family in context.member.Include("profileFamilyParents.custProfileChild")
                    .Where(wherep)
                      select family).Single();

Mapper.CreateMap<Cust_ProfileTbl, EFWeb.ViewModels.Profile>();

EFWeb.ViewModels.Profile customerViewItem = Mapper.Map<Cust_ProfileTbl, EFWeb.ViewModels.Profile>(rs);
```

Comment: Doesn't work? Please elaborate as in, what is the error?

Comment: no error, just the custmerViewItem does not have data after execute this line Mapper.CreateMap<List<Cust_ProfileTbl>, List<EFWeb.ViewModels.Profile>>();
List<EFWeb.ViewModels.Profile> customerViewItem = Mapper.Map<List<Cust_ProfileTbl>, List<EFWeb.ViewModels.Profile>>(rs);

Comment: Where and how are you initializing your CreateMap()?

Comment: Try changing your CreateMap to `Mapper.CreateMap<Cust_ProfileTbl, EFWeb.ViewModels.Profile>();`. Automapper while handle the lists itself. You would also need to make the same changes to the type parameters of the Map method.

Comment: @DavidL, I follow the sample from this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper. and i think you mean this line -->  Mapper.CreateMap<List<Cust_ProfileTbl>, List<EFWeb.ViewModels.Profile>>(); and this is all code i have.

Comment: @grin0048, i make the changes but it throw me error i edited the changed code as above. Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl -> ProfileFamily
EFWeb.Models.Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl -> EFWeb.ViewModels.ProfileFamily

Destination path:
Profile.profileFamilyParents.profileFamilyParents.profileFamilyParents0[0]

Source value:
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Cust_ProfileFamilyTb_748391D9FF1EE1613B7BD5D4FC5C3610E2034A5324B54FD4C38FCDDD945B7D7F

Comment: You'll need to provide automapper with a map for mapping the Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl type to the EFWeb.ViewModels.ProfileFamily type.

Comment: @grin0048 appreciate if you could give me a link on doing this. Thanks.

Comment: Try adding a second CreateMap below your first: `Mapper.CreateMap<Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl, EFWeb.ViewModels.ProfileFamily>();`

Comment: Yes!working.. Thanks. was trying the same line as you mentioned above. Do you mind to put it as answer and i will mark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is you should not create a map for mapping a `List<A>` to a `List<B>`. You should just create a map from `A` to `B`--automapper knows how to map a `List<A>` to a `List<B>` if you give it a map from `A` to `B`. This means your map should be:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Cust_ProfileTbl, EFWeb.ViewModels.Profile>();
```

Second, automapper will not know how to map your `ICollection<Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl>` properties in your entity to the `ICollection<ProfileFamily>` properties in your viewmodel. You need to provide a map for those types:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Cust_ProfileFamilyTbl, EFWeb.ViewModels.ProfileFamily>();
```

Comment: 1 up for the line "First thing is you should not create a map for mapping a List<A> to a List<B>".

Answer (score 1):

It is always bet to initialize your maps inside of the startup entry point of the app.  In an MVC project this would be in the global.asax and in a WPF application it would be the app.xaml.cs file.

If we were initializing in the global.asax, it would look something like this:

```
protected void Application_Startup()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Cust_ProfileTbl, EFWeb.ViewModels.Profile>();
}
```

Notice we're not mapping from type to type, not from list of type to list of type, meaning we need to iteratively map.

```
List<EFWeb.ViewModels.Profile> customerViewItem = rs.Select(x => Mapper.Map<Cust_ProfileTbl>(x)).ToList();
```

Now, there's a good chance that your map will still fail, since your properties do not match on each side.  If this is the case, you should use .IgnoreMember() extension methods on your CreateMap to ignore the members that cannot be mapped because they have no corresponding receiving type.